# How to make MapView marker stay at given coordinate when zooming or pinching?

Tags: google-maps, react-native

I'm currently working with the MapView.Marker on React Native, which now I can set the marker location through the code and it all seems to work fine until I zoom in/out or pinch the screen like this

[image]

[image]

as the images above is shown that the marker has been slightly move out of its location

the code I use to pin the marker is

```
    onRegionChange = region => {
        this.setState({
          region
        })
    }

    setMarkerRegion = () => {
        const { region } = this.state;
        this.setState({
          markerRegion: region,
          locationMarked: true,
        });
    }
    <MapView
          ref={m => { this.map = m }}
          style={{ flex: 10 }}
          initialRegion={region}
          onRegionChangeComplete={this.onRegionChange}
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          customMapStyle={customStyles}>
      <Marker
        coordinate={{
             latitude: markerRegion.latitude,
             longitude: markerRegion.longitude
        }}
        style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}
        title={"This is a title <3"}
        description={searchLocation}
      />
    </MapView>
<TouchableOpacity style={[styles.markerFixed]} onPress={this.setMarkerRegion}>
  <Icon name={'map-marker'} color={'white'} type='font-awesome' containerStyle={styles.marker}></Icon>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

I'm try searching on SO but there are only an example on native android which is not helpful in this case, any idea would be appreciated.